# Windows 8.1 downgrade is not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, windows-8.1, downgrade

A while back I upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 because it worked fine on my desktop. From the get go I realized that wasn't a good idea. My laptop has run significantly slower ever since, and every 'fix' I found didn't resolve my problems. I've decided to rollback to Windows 8.1 (what was preinstalled on my PC) because it actually worked well on my laptop.

As is obvious by my posting this question, it hasn't been cooperating with me. I have Windows 8.1 on a USB, and I've booted up the laptop through the USB. However, every time I try to install Windows 8.1, when I click on the button to "Upgrade" to Windows 8.1, it basically tells me that I have to boot the laptop up normally and THEN run the upgrade. When I try THAT, it tells me that it can't find the proper installation instructions after I put in the product key.

I'm so confused. I haven't messed with OS's before, so I have no experience with this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How long ago is "awhile ago" you only have between 15 and 30 days to roll back to the previous version of Windows depending on what version of Windows 10 you updated too.  Please clarify what OS your running now.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10. It is past the cutoff date to rollback to Windows 8.1 normally. I know that you are supposed to be able to boot Windows 8.1 from a USB or CD and roll back that way, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: What you describe wouldn't be "rolling back to Windows 8.1" it would be installing Windows 8.1 over your current installation of Windows 10.  I am still confused what you are trying to achieve.